# Holding Airspeed at Military Fields

Tags: holding

I read in the AIM, 5-3-8 j.2.b.3 that holding airspeeds at USAF airfields only are 310 KIAS maximum, unless otherwise depicted. I interpreted this to mean that any holding pattern on an approach plate for a USAF airfield unless published otherwise had a max speed of 310. An examiner claimed that actually it means that the max speed of 310 applies only to holding patterns based off of the navaid located directly on the airfield. I have not seen that written and I think the correct interpretation is the one that assumes that the max airspeed applies to any holding pattern associated with an IAP at a USAF field unless published otherwise.

Comment: In my opinion your interpretation is correct.

Comment: I'm with @RTO.  That speed has more to do with performance range of USAF aircraft types than the holding point references.  Stubby winged airplanes don't like being "too slow."  I think about the T-38 for example which is well known for potentially getting in trouble quickly in a base turn, or when circling where the '38 is a category E.

Comment: Can you provide an example chart? I think the examiner may be closer to correct in actual practice. For many military procedures, civilian NAVAIDs are used for arrival holding patterns. The 8260-2 form for that NAVAID will indicate all of the procedures that it is used on, and the restrictions. It would not surprise me that an otherwise ‘standard’ holding pattern would not show a speed restriction.